# How to connect LLM to Multiple SQL database with LangChain SQLChain

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I want to connect LLM to more than 2 SQL database with SQLDatabaseChain. Please let me know if it is possible or any other way.

I have connected to 1 DB and able to work. bUt my case i need to connect to more than 1 DB and its table

Comment: If I answered this question please check it, if you found a better answer please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment but this may suffice for an answer. It appears you cannot. Or at least, it's not a supported feature.

wadihpazos: Not with the current implementation. The agent takes a dbengine object which is tied to one connection alone. Interested in your specific use case. Maybe the right solution is working multiple agents in parallel with the same prompt across different data sources.
[SOURCE](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/2356)

It seems someone wanted to do something similar [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/7581), but no solution has been posted.